# WPF Custom Panel From ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, itemscontrol

I want to create a custom panel where the items are rendered as buttons with close button (x) inside. What i did so far is create a custom control that derives from ItemsControl and set the templates for itemspanel and itemtemplate like this:

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="SandBox1.CustomControls.WorkspacePanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class WorkspacePanel : ItemsControl
{
    public WorkspacePanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

However when i set the ItemsSource i get nothing. Any help?

## EDIT

Using the custom control:

```
<cc:WorkspacePanel ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"/>
```

Workspaces is of type `ObservableCollection<WorkspaceModel>` and WorkspaceModel is:

```
public class WorkspaceModel
{
    public WorkspaceModel(string name, bool isActive)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.IsActive = isActive;
    }

    public bool IsActive  { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`RelativeSource.TemplatedParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent.aspx) is for `ControlTemplates`, here you should just bind to the DataContext by not specifying any source:

```
{Binding Path=Name}
```

or simply

```
{Binding Name}
```

**Edit:** The control being a custom control i would ditch this approach (i don't know if it even can work) like that unless maybe you manually write a lot of code VS would normally write for you.

When you created the control and your project did not have a generic theme yet it should have created a `Themes` folder and a `Generic.xaml`, in that class you can set the properties in the style instead (note the `BasedOn` which gets the template and other properties from the default ItemsControl):

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SandBox1.CustomControls">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:WorkspacePanel}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ItemsControl}}">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Then the data-item possibly has no public property called `Name`.

Comment: I think the problem is that you try to define the appearance of your control like that, i don't think that works, did you create that XAML file on your own to "template" your control?

Comment: Yes i did the xaml myself and it's not the first time.